# Try and catch block. Which solution is better

Tags: c#, design-patterns, try-catch

It seemed a reasonable pattern for me to use:

```
int.TryParse()
```

and simple if, rather than:

```
int.Parse()
```

inside the try block. Till I found this sample in MS pattern & practices

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Update a setting value for our application. If the setting does not
    /// exist, then add the setting.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Key"></param>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool AddOrUpdateValue(string Key, Object value)
    {
        bool valueChanged = false;
        try
        {
            // if new value is different, set the new value.
            if (isolatedStore[Key] != value)
            {
                isolatedStore[Key] = value;
                valueChanged = true;
            }
        }
        catch (KeyNotFoundException)
        {
            isolatedStore.Add(Key, value);
            valueChanged = true;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            isolatedStore.Add(Key, value);
            valueChanged = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception while using IsolatedStorageSettings: " + e.ToString());
        }

        return valueChanged;
    }
```

Isn't it better to use Contains method insted? On the other hand, I have read that CLR can optimize try-catch to simple goto.

Comment: Am I missing something? What do Parse and TryParse have to do with the longer code sample?

Comment: I think he's referencing the differences in the patterns implemented by `Parse()` and `TryParse()`; namely that one throws exceptions that should be handled and one uses a bool to allow an `if` test. In his code sample you can see they use the former method to handle flow control instead of using `isolatedStore.Contains()` and an `if` statement to guide the flow.

Comment: @Justin: The point is that the sample is using the `KeyNotFoundException` thrown by the indexer instead of checking if the item exists using a `Contains` call. The former is equivalent to `int.Parse`, the latter to `int.TryParse`. The OP wants to know why do the exception handling version instead of the "try" version.

Comment: The sample code swallows exception - not good.

Comment: @Martin, if an exception handler *completely handles* an exception, why would you *want* it to bubble up?  Or are you referring to the last handler wherein he logs the exception?  I don't see a problem in either case.  (though personally, I never use exception handling for control flow -- only for genuine error cases.)

Comment: @Kirk Woll. The code does not handle say an `OutOfMemoryException`. Granted, in a debug build it will write to any attached debugger, but that can hardly be considered logging. Anyway the program is now in a corrupted state but continues to execute without knowing that. Exceptions that cannot be handled should always bubble to the top level of the application where fatal exception handling should take place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, do not use catch blocks for this.  I'm not sure where you found that code but I suspect it's incredibly old.  The Contains() method is much faster. Additionally, check out the [TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx)() method of the dictionary class.

Comment: It is not. it's super new :)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637516%28v=VS.92%29.aspx
Setting Sample

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what type isolatedStore is supposed to be, but if it is a Dictionary, then `isolatedStore.TryGetValue(key, out value)` would be my preferred way of checking.

And for assignment, `isolatedStore[key] = value` should never throw an exception unless key is null, which seems fair to let bubble up to the caller.  Essentially, using the indexer is a add-or-update operation by itself, although it won't tell you if the value was previously there.

So yes, just like `int.Parse` vs `int.TryParse`, prefer the methods that give you responses you can deal with (like `TryGetValue`) rather than methods that throw exceptions (at least in recoverable situations like these).

Ben Voigt brings up a great point about thread safety.  Using TryGetValue and assigning the value with the `indexer (isolatedStore[key])` instead of `.Add()` will eliminate any exceptions, but the operation still won't be atomic.

Comment: @Chris: Thanks!

@Raj: Thanks for the formatting changes, usually I'm better about that.

Answer (score 1):

I've run tests and TryParse ran much quicker than Parse because .NET seemed to spend a lot of time generating the exception to throw if Parse failed, but in TryParse it was able to just throw out a "false."

I'm not sure that either one is "better", but my tests said that TryParse seemed to be faster, and I think TryParse makes for more readable code than lots of try/catch blocks.

Edit: your code sample doesn't seem to have anything to do with int parsing.

Answer (score 1):

`TryGetValue` is better than `Contains` because it avoids a race condition.  But if you have multiple threads accessing the Dictionary you'll have to handle exceptions one way or another, although you can minimize the number of times you pay the exception penalty.

Comment: Dictionaries are not inherrently thread-safe, so I don't see how the race condition applies.  If two threads try to write to your dictionary and you are not locking, you are already in deep trouble. (and of course if the writes need to be locked, so do the reads)  My understanding is that TryGetValue is better because it requires only a *single* hash lookup into the dictionary, instead of one for Contains and the other to fetch the value.

Comment: Just a difference in granularity on the locking.  And different types of "better".  Better correctness because it's more atomic, better performance because it's only one hash lookup.